# Cannot use Bower because of node.js error

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower

I'm trying to use bower to install everything for the website I am working on, but every time I try to use it, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toLowerCase'
at Function.Buffer.isEncoding (buffer.js:240:32)
at assertEncoding (evalmachine.<anonymous>:98:27)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:908:3)
at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:64:8)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:11)
at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
at defaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:40:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

I have been searching for a while on the internet but cannot manage to find the solution for this problem.

I am trying to run it on Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: which version of bower are you using? are you getting this error on installing bower itself or a particular dependency?

Comment: I am using bower 1.6.3
I use npm to install bower (sudo npm install -g bower)
The errors are coming whenever I try to use bower, even when only calling it with no parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by downloading the Node.js sources and by recompiling it.